# Building a kernel for Android: multiple target patterns

Tags: android, makefile, kernel

I am trying to build a kernel for Android following the instructions [here](https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html).

Checking out the msm/angler:

```
git checkout -b android-msm-angler-3.10-marshmallow-mr1 origin/android-msm-angler-3.10-marshmallow-mr1
```

After `make angler_defconfig`, `make` results in the following error.

```
Makefile:796: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

Would somebody help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Moved URL to hyperlink, updated formatting.

Comment: I resolved it. The culprit was permission to run ./scripts/link-vmlinux.sh.

Comment: Awesome. Please post that as your answer below, and then accept that answer once the site allows (after 2 days).

Comment: I found out later, it was not the ultimate solution. I got still errors.:
'sudo make' can proceed the building somehow, but stops soon. I guess that I have some error in a configuration file.

Comment: In that case, you'll want to update your question to include what you've tried, and the results thereof. As it is worded right now, everyone will assume this is still solved. (Edits also move your question back up the queue, AFAIK).

Answer (score 2):

You can change prebuilts gcc
from:

```
arm/arm-eabi-X.X
```

to:

```
aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-X.X
```

Comment: This worked for me as i was using the wrong toolchain.

Comment: Confirming that this worked for me to build a bullhead kernel -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. go to aosp files.
   In my scenario:
   cd /aosp_files/out/target/product/angler

type in terminal:

```
dd if=kernel bs=1 skip=$(LC_ALL=C grep -a -b -o $'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' kernel | cut -d ':' -f 1) | zgrep -a 'Linux version'
```

-> then You will see output with commit sha-1

```
Linux version 3.10.73-gde1f200
```

2. copy your sha-1 after 'g' -> de1f200
3. go to your kernel_files

   git checkout your_sha1
4. then

   export PATH=$(pwd)/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin:$PATH

   export ARCH=arm64

   export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-
5. make angler_defconfig

   make -j4
6. If You will get error

   make distclean
7. repat from 4.
8. Should work : )